# Shaking a virtual wiimote

Tags: controllers, wiimote, super-mario-galaxy-2, dolphin-emulator

I have Super Mario Galaxy 2 in the Dolphin Emulator. Since I have to point for certain things and use the joystick on the nunchuck for general movement (and I don't have a USB sensor bar), I want to play with the nunchuck in my left hand and the computer mouse in my right hand, while the Wiimote just lies around (because I don't have a third hand).

Everything works fine except for shaking the Wiimote (and a certain nunchuck problem, but that's a different question). I set <kbd>shake X</kbd> to the middle mouse button (<kbd>Click 2</kbd>) in the hybrid Wiimote settings and it does rapidly shake the cursor around, but it doesn't make Mario spin.

Interestingly, if I click <kbd>Movie</kbd>-><kbd>Start recording input</kbd>, shaking suddenly works completely fine, but Mario keeps ducking and no input from the real Wiimote (or nunchuck) are accepted anymore. And apparently I can't turn recording off again by any other way than closing the game.

Setup:
American version of Super Mario Galaxy 2 (SB401?)
Dolphin 5.0 (ac267a29405ae768037a8774b84b805a4180d1af)
Windows 7 Professional 64bit +SP1

**How do I shake the virtual part of the hybrid Wiimote?**
If it's possible to just fix the "Start recording" behaviour, that would also be ok, although inconvenient, because I would have to click it every time I start the game.

([Possibly related question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/320850/dolphin-emulator-nunchuck-stuck-in-forward-right-direction))

Comment: Those are not keys on a keyboard.

Comment: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7437/using-code-ticks-for-technical-term-highlighting-considered-harmful

Comment: Yes, I know that post. And I disagree. Formatting is there to make the post easier to read or to emphasise, not to follow strict rules. Quotation marks are not the formatting I prefer here.

Comment: You can't "disagree" with semantic meaning. Using code tags implies using code. If not, you're wrong and it should be changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69357/discussion-between-fabian-and-danmakugrazer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an [answer from one of the developers of Dolphin](https://forums.dolphin-emu.org/Thread-shaking-a-virtual-wiimote?pid=457901) ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20180430113357/https://forums.dolphin-emu.org/Thread-shaking-a-virtual-wiimote?pid=457901)): This is a bug in the current version of Dolphin. It only affects hybrid Wiimote mode, emulated Wiimote mode works.

Answer (score 0):

From what I found, it helps to increase the shake intensity in the shake settings. Go to motion settings, then find shake, and look for the intensity option (it's underneath the options that set what key you press to emulate the shake,) then just increase it to like, 35cm or something.

This should work for both normal and hybrid.

Comment: Since I asked this question, version 5.0 got from beta to release. It doesn't even contain the hybrid wiimote feature anymore, because they saw it as too broken. So no, it doesn't work with a hybrid wiimote, because that feature no longer exists. :D